# trouble getting mod_wsgi.so working with django

Tags: python, django, xampp

I am starting to learn django , and I'm trying to set up a development environment as in http://www.venkysblog.com/setup-django-on-windows-with-apache-and-mysql. I'm having trouble getting it working and so I'm working backwards to make sure I have it all correct.

I'm ok up to step 5. I have confirmed python , xampp and django working . I have created a DB called django using phpmyadmin. I have confirmed a connection between mysql and django using

```
manage.py syncdb
```

In step 5 following the directions I have downloaded the correct mod_wsgi.so and put it into F:\xampp\apache\modules folder, I have added to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

The article author the states:

```
Before we move further, copy your Django testProject folder into "C:/wamp/www".
This is not mandatory, but I did this, and the remaining instructions below are based on that.
```

I have not been able to get past this point. What can I do from this point to confirm that python/django is working properly with the mod_wsgi.so

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite understand what your problem is. You say you can't "get past" the point where the author recommends you copy your testProject folder. What happens?

However, I must say that this is a very very bad tutorial. Taking that copy step for example, not only is that "not mandatory", it is very strongly recommended against. There is no good reason to have your project code under the web root, and plenty of reasons not to: it is a potential security risk, given that a misconfiguration could easily expose your code files to the web, including your settings.py containing things like your db passwords.

There is however an even more serious problem with this tutorial. It is not a good idea to try and get things set up with mod_wsgi for development purposes, and even less when you're just starting out. Django includes a development server (`manage.py runserver`) for exactly this reason, and it is a much better idea to use that for development, and postpone learning about Apache/mod_wsgi until you are ready for deployment.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the detailed answer. I am coming from the PHP world and have enjoyed having phpmyadmin to easily visualize my mysql DBs, which is why I wanted to go with a WAMP/XAMPP stack and plug in python/django. Is there a similar program with django /python to visually see the DB and tables? How do you do this?

Comment: The two things are not in any way related. You can continue to use phpMyAdmin via WAMP while using the dev server to serve your Django app. However, there are plenty of desktop tools to access MySQL databases, starting with the the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) itself.

Comment: Ok I think I see now , so you are saying just skip step 5 in the tutorial, develop using the built in server and XAMPPs Mysql and when needed check the the db using phpmyadmin ? Now that you point it out it seems obvious - Bill